# Why are the Dragon Balls in episode 41 small if they are Namekian?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

I'm watching DBZ again as an adult, and when Bulma, Krillin & Gohan meet two medical namekians, these people help them find some dragon balls.

I remember namekian dragon balls were very big, but these ones can be held by hand.

Why are they small?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In episode 41, Bulma and crew are not on namek, and the 2 "medical namekians" are actually 2 different aliens.

[image]

They are playing a mind game on Krillin Gohan, and Bulma. The reason then, that the dragon balls are still "small" is because these aliens only had the memories of the 3 of them to go off of, so the earth dragonballs. In a couple more episodes when they finally reach Namek is the first time we find out about the larger namekian dragon balls.

Comment: Commenting just to add that This is the "Fake namek saga" which is purely filler